# basic pointer question in c++ program

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, variable-assignment

I looking for a clarification regarding the pointers. I have compiled the following code in bordland c++ 5.5.1 without any errors. But while i am trying to execute gives a core error.

```
int main ()
{
    int x=10,y=20;

     int &a=x;
     int &b=y;

     int *c;
     int *d;

     *c=x;
     *d=y;

return 0;
}
```

Basically I am trying to create two reference variable (a,b) and assigned with two variables (x,y). after that I created two pointer variable(c,d) and tried to assign same variables (x,y). This gives me error while exection and not at compilation.

whether I am doing any wrong, this is not a standard assignments of pointer variable. why the pointer assignment is getting failed at this point. Please help me to understand this.

1st Update:

Thanks to all. First, I understood that I am working on a C++ feature (reference variable).
Second, I need to allocate memory for the pointer variables before play with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you posted is C++, not C. And your problem is that you need to make those pointers actually point at something:

```
int * c = & x;   // make c point at x
* c = 42;        // changes x
```

Comment: So the assignement "int &a=x;" is not supported by C. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: "int & a = x" declares a reference - references are part of C++, not C.

Comment: Thanks Neil, the problem is, I am using cpp compiler and by default the files are stored with cpp extention so all c++ features are supported at compilation

Comment: You might want to consider switching to the MinGW compiler and use the Code::Blocks IDE - see http://www.codeblocks.org

Answer (score 2):

You have declared c and d as int pointers and you are trying to update their pointed values, they aren't pointing to anywhere valid since you never initialize them with valid memory.

Try c = &x; and then play with c.

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing an invalid pointer. 'c' and 'd' were not assigned a memory location and so will be using whatever was previously in memory as their location. You need to do:

```
int *c = new int;
int *d = new int;
```

Comment: Or point them to some valid memory e.g. c = &x (set c so it points to the same memory as x, just as "int &a=x" sets a to point to the same memory as x)

Comment: If you assign memory to them in this way, make sure you don't forget to clear the memory when you're are done with them.  Use: delete c; delete d;

Also the way to do this in C: int *c = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));  And when done: free(c);

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're not entirely clear on the syntax.

Typing `int *c` is tricky, because it looks like you're declaring an integer with the name `*c`. However, this is not the case. This will declare a pointer to an integer, and in C/C++, pointers to a certain type are denoted by appending a `*` after the type name. Thus, you're declaring a variable of type `int*` (pointer to an integer), with the name `c`, even though the spacing makes it look different. For the record, typing `int* c` yields the same result, and is arguably more readable.

It follows then that typing `*c` does not reference your variable, as it is actually called `c`. Instead, what this does is dereference the pointer: it returns whatever object the pointer is pointing to. Or, if the pointer is invalid, cause an error.

If you want to declare a pointer and set it to point to an object at a later point, you need to do this:

```
int *c;

// stuff goes here

c = &x;
```

`&x` will return `x`'s address in memory, which can be assigned to a pointer as a value. Then, you can manipulate the value through the pointer by dereferencing it: e.g. `*c = 15`.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined two pointer variables c and d but you have not allocated any memory for them. You need to assign some memory to both of them.

Do this:

```
int *c = &x;
int *d = &y;
```